# FHIR Issue trying to search by date range

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to do a /Observation search by value-quantity, I can do it without problems with the prefixes eq, ne, gt, lt, le etc but I can't do it for a range, I would like to be able to do it for a minimum and maximum value.

Is this possible? I have searched on composite search but I have not been able to...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range searches in FHIR are done using a lower bound combined with an upper bound since multiple conditions are ANDed together. If you wanted to search for Observations with a value between 1 and 10 you could do

```
Observation?value-quantity=ge1&value-quantity=le10
```

Comment: This method works, it returns the correct results but with an issue, I think it is not the correct way "diagnostics": "The search parameter 'le10' is not supported for resource type 'Observation'."

Comment: There may be an issue with how you constructed the query, `le10` shouldn't be a search parameter, it should be a value. What FHIR server are you using? I checked with HAPI, test.fhir.org and GCP's FHIR API and all of them accept the query in my answer

Comment: Hello, sorry it was my fault... I was calling my backend and not test.fhir.org, the backend had some errors...

Thank you!